# gtk-rs: Does a gtk4 widget hold a reference to its callbacks while a gtk3 widget doesn't?

Tags: gtk-rs

I am porting a working gtk-rs application from gtk3 to gtk4. The following code is a reduced self-contained example to demonstrate the Problem. The code is for gtk3 with the changes required for gtk4 indicated by comments.

```
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{ApplicationWindow, DrawingArea};
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Ctx {
    text: String,
    _drawing_area: gtk::DrawingArea,
}

impl Drop for Ctx {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("DROP");
    }
}

fn on_activate(app: &gtk::Application) {
    let drawing_area = DrawingArea::builder().build();

    let win = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .application(app)
        .child(&drawing_area)
        .build();

    // gtk3:
    win.show_all();

    // gkt4:
    //win.show();

    let ctx = Ctx {
        text: "Hallo".into(),
        _drawing_area: drawing_area.clone(),
    };
    let shared_context = Rc::new(RefCell::new(ctx));

    {
        let shared_context = shared_context.clone();

        // gtk3:
        drawing_area.connect_draw(move |_area, _cairo| {
            let ctx = shared_context.borrow();
            println!("draw text= \"{}\"", ctx.text);
            gtk::Inhibit(false)
        });

        // gtk4:
        //drawing_area.set_draw_func(move |_area, _cairo, _width, _height| {
        //    let ctx = shared_context.borrow();
        //    println!("draw text= \"{}\"", ctx.text);
        //});        
    }
}

fn main() {
    let app = gtk::Application::builder().build();
    app.connect_activate(on_activate);
    app.run();
    println!("main loop finished");
}
```

With gtk3, the code works as intended: The Ctx structure is dropped when the window is closed:

```
     Running `target/debug/droptest`
draw text= "Hallo"
DROP
main loop finished
```

With gtk4, however, the Ctx structure is not dropped:

```
     Running `target/debug/droptest`
draw text= "Hallo"
main loop finished
```

I see, that there is a circular reference ctx -> drawing_area -> draw_func -> closure -> shared_context -> ctx. I assume that is the reason, that ctx is not dropped with gtk4.

However, I'd expected gtk3 and gtk4 (-rs) to behave identically. Where does the difference come from? Is it documented?

Any suggestions to solve the problem with gtk4? The closure could get a weak reference, but then ctx would be dropped when `on_active()` is finished. Is there an elegant way to reference ctx from the ApplicationWindows once? In reality, of course, Ctx contains many widgets and other data  and there are multiple callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

As nobody jumped on this, I try to answer that myself:

The observed different behavior can be demonstrated with the C api of gtk as well, it is not rooted in gtk-rs. Circular reference are not reliably resolved by the gtk runtime, although sometimes it works with gtk3 when a window is closed.

See [Why does gtk3 call the ClosureNotify function in the example code, but gkt4 doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74915106/why-does-gtk3-call-the-closurenotify-function-in-the-example-code-but-gkt4-does)

The possible approaches to resolve the problem of the reference cycle mentioned in the link above work for gtk-rs, too:

- Subclass one of the widgets and make the ctx data part of it
- For gtk4: Use a "win.close" action
- Use weak references in ctx